# FederationException ID3206 in MVC application deployed to AWS EC2 instance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, azure, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an MVC5 EF6 application configured to authenticate using organizational authentication (Azure AD) which works fine when running in IIS Express on my development PC. It was developed using Visual Studio 2013.

I have now deployed the application to an AWS EC2 instance using the Cloud Formation wizard in the AWS Visual Studio toolkit. I have also reconfigured the application entry in the Azure AD to run against the deployed version instead of the development version.

When the application is run by navigating to the ec2 instance from a browser, the user is presented with the Microsoft authentication page, so I know the deployed app is running. After successful authentication I get the following error:

ID3206: A SignInResponse message may only redirect within the current web application: '/' is not allowed.

I have tried all the potential solutions I can find from SO and other forums concerning this issue. These include several different ways of ensuring a backslash is at the end of a URL. However, none of these approaches fixes my issue.

My issue seems to be slightly different in that the error states that:

```
application: '/' is not allowed
```

All other similar references I've seen have something like:

```
application: '/appname' is not allowed
```

My application does not have this issue in development using IIS Express.

Can anyone offer any potential solutions or avenues to research concerning this?

Comment: Julian, can you trace the singin request being sent by your deployed app using fiddler and paste here?

Comment: I certainly will Dushyant but I don't know how to do what you are requesting. Can you include some instruction please.

Comment: install and fire up fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), enable https tracing in fiddler (http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/DecryptHTTPS). Open a browser, target fiddler to trace requests only from that browser (drag the fiddler command bar button "Any Process" to the browser instance). Navigate to your deployed application' URL in the browser, click on sign-in. In fiddler double click on the sign-in request sent to https://login.windows.net. Click on the "Raw" tab in the upper right pane to get the raw request. Copy and paste here.

Comment: I've done what you've requested but I cannot paste it here because its too long by 6159 characters. Can you tell me what I need to look for in the raw request?

Comment: I want to understand where the error is coming from. Is the signin request reaching AzureAD? Is AzureAD sending back a successful response? If so, what host is returning that error? By the way, you can modify your question and add the request response sequence from the trace.

Comment: Added the request trace for Dushyant

Comment: Julian, what you've added is the saml token posted by login.microsoftonline.com to login.windows.net. This looks good. I am interested in seeing the next step - where login.windows.net posts a response back to your application. And also the step where the error occurs.

Comment: Dushyant, I've added the raw response to the login.windows.net request. The next item in Fiddler is the HTTP 500 result. I've added the raw request & response for that. Many thanks for your help. Can you see anything in the data I've added?

Comment: The error is from the windows identity foundation stack - beyond my area of expertise. Julian, we recommend that new applications use our ASP.NET OWIN stack for OpenIDConnect. Can you try that: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet?

Answer (score 0):

The redirect error only occurs using the Amazon Cloud Formation tool (inside the AWS Explorer in VisualStudio) to deploy to AWS. If Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk tool is used instead to reply to AWS, the redirect after successful authentication works fine.

Deploying to Azure using VisualStudio results in a successful redirect too.

So, although this is not a definitive answer as to why the Cloud Formation deployment causes the redirect error, using Amazon Elastic Beanstalk instead will redirect correctly.